# c++ - Initialize standard stream objects

Tags: c++, io, stream, initialization

In what cases and why is this necessary:

```
class ios_base::Init {
    static int init_cnt;  // internal static counter (for exposition only)
public:
    Init();
    ~Init();
}
```

Have it from this site: [cpluplus.com - ios_base::init](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios_base/Init/)

I read the description and meditated about it, but this did not help much...

Comment: The internal counter? For keeping track of how many objects were created, for one. Could be used as an overly simple way of generating unique object ids.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but that is not my question. On the page I linked it says: "This class is an instantiation of basic_ios designed to serve as base class for all wide stream classes, with wchar_t as character type (see basic_ios for more info on the template)." I do not understand what this actually means...

Comment: Are you asking why the `Init` class exists at all? From your link - so that standard stream objects "are constructed and properly initialized." Why does that matter? Cos globals are evil.

Comment: But are they not automatically constructed when I do something like "cout << "test" << endl;" -  I guess I misunderstand something fundamentally.

Comment: @Michael, for you to call `operator<<` on `cout`, its must already be a valid object. Which means it must have been previously constructed.

Comment: But the linker does that automatically right? But I read that sometimes I have for force this, right? In what cases is that necessary?

Comment: @Michael: They're automatically constructed at some point before `main` begins, but not necessarily before you first use them (for example, if you use them when initialising a global variable). That's sometimes known as the "static initialisation fiasco", and is why globals are even more evil in C++ than in most other languages.

Comment: @Michael And how would the linker do it automatically?  The linker doesn't know `std::cout` from `myStaticVariable`; how would it know that `std::cout` has to be constructed first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a workaround for the [static initialization order fiasco](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/static-init-order.html). Essentially, if you want to use the global stream objects from a static initializer, you can call this to ensure that they're all constructed in time. Runtimes I'm familiar with already do this properly, but technically speaking that's not guaranteed.

(Note also that as of C++11, it *is* guaranteed.)

Comment: The implementation of the standard library and supporting utilities. The iostreams library is part of the runtime library.

Comment: What is guaranteed in C++11?  As far as I can see, the guarantees are exactly the same as they've been since CFront (pre C++98).  And which runtimes guarantee that the global stream objects are always constructed first.  (I'm pretty sure that g++ doesn't, since it's `crt0` is in C, not in C++.)

Answer (score 1):

They're needed to ensure the correct initialization of the
standard iostream objects, like `std::cout`.  Basically, the
standard iostream objects are guaranteed to be constructed by
the time the first constructor of `ios_base::Init` has finished.
(The `init_cnt` member is part of one technique of achieving
this.)  In addition, the standard says that including
`<iostream>` declares a static instance of `ios_base::Init` (or
behaves as if it does), so if you write:

```
#include <iostream>

class X
{
public:
    X() { std::cout << "something";
};
X anXwithStaticLifetime;
```

you're guaranteed that `std::cout` will be constructed before
the constructor of `anXwithStaticLifetime` is run.

Of course, this only works within a single translation unit.  If
you define in a header ("X.hh"):

```
class X
{
public:
    X();
};
```

and then in two different translation units:

```
#include "X.hh"
#include <iostream>

X::X()
{
    std::cout << "something";
}
```

and:

```
#include "X.hh"
X anXwithStaticLifetime;
```

it's quite possible that `std::cout` will not have been
constructed when you execute the constructor.  The usual way of
ensuring this is to define a local instance of `ios_base::Init`
in the constructor:

```
X::X()
{
    static ios_base::Init toEnsureInitialization;
    std::cout << "something";
}
```

In practice, most implementations use additional tricks to
reduce the risk.  But as far as I know, none of them are 100%,
and depending on how you link, you can still get into problems.
But they won't occur if you do things the usual way.  With the
results that a lot of programmers aren't aware of the risk, and
don't make the necessary declaration (and it almost always works
anyway).